# How to optimize CLASS function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm profiling JavaScript using dynaTrace AJAX edition.

According to the tool's "Hot Spots", the following jQuery method is using the majority of execution time:

```
CLASS(*, *, undefined, *, undefined, false): false
```

...it has over 700 invocations on my page.

What is this call and how can I optimize it?

I'm using jQuery version 1.4.2. The performance issues are primarily in IE6 and IE7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you should be optimizing the **selectors** you're passing into jQuery, not jQuery's selector engine itself.  Perhaps you could identify the most common selectors you use, or find a way to identify the slowest.  We may be able to help optimize those if you provide them.

Comment: Is the CLASS() method invoked whenever I am using ".classname" selectors?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a method named `CLASS` within it, but I dynaTrace means the selector engine based on what you've described.  Not sure where it got `CLASS` from.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, upgrade to [jQuery **1.4.3**](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/10/16/jquery-143-released/) which has major improvements in this area for newer browsers...by optimize, I mean this doesn't even get called most of the time.  Instead it's [using the `querySelectorAll()` if it exists](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/10/16/jquery-143-released/), making the entire selector process *much* cheaper.

Comment: My performance issues are in IE6 and IE7 (updated question to reflect this). Those browsers don't support querySelectorAll(). Thanks for the suggestion though.